# Calculate the plane angle from 2D plane

Tags: 3d, rotations, projective-geometry

I am analysing a squared plane from a perfect cube. This plane is distorted by the perspective view of a camera.

[image]

I would like to know ask please, some approaches of how could I get to know  the orientation of the cube towards the camera, based on the distortion of the plane mentioned before.

Thank you very much